# Is Subresource Integrity actually working?

Tags: cdn, subresource-integrity

I've decided to add SRI to our CDN scripts, but I want to test if it's working. If I manually change the hash the script still loads. I'd be expecting some kind of error code or something in the console.

So for instance, this is the correct hash:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ= sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ sha512-jGsMH83oKe9asCpkOVkBnUrDDTp8wl+adkB2D+//JtlxO4SrLoJdhbOysIFQJloQFD+C4Fl1rMsQZF76JjV0eQ=="
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

If I then change the first characters in each of the sha hashes to:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-YosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ= sha384-mvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ sha512-iGsMH83oKe9asCpkOVkBnUrDDTp8wl+adkB2D+//JtlxO4SrLoJdhbOysIFQJloQFD+C4Fl1rMsQZF76JjV0eQ=="
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

I would expect it to fail. But it doesn't. Tested in Firefox 58.0.2 and Chrome 64.0.3282.140, both of which support SRI. Caching is turned off and I can see in the developer tools that the script is being re-fetched each time.

Is there anything else I can do to verify that SRI is being used? Have I fundamentally misunderstood something...?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it with some style sheets and it seems to be working there, including the Console in Firefox reporting:

> None of the “sha384” hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource.

It's also far more obvious the stylesheets haven't loaded. I think there must be a caching issue with scripts.

Comment: As an aside, I can't get Google's Font APIs to work with this at all. I get a hash but they always fail. I suspect there's tracking embedded which means the payload changes on each request, breaking the hash.